# Animating margin change in Android flickers

Tags: android, animation

In my Android app I want to hide/show a `Toolbar` in an animation and adjust the `FrameLayout` below it so that it always fills up the whole screen. I do that by animating the top margin of the `FrameLayout` according to the display status of the `Toolbar`:

```
public void toggleToolbars(final boolean show) {
    mToolbarHidden = !show;
    final Toolbar tt = getBaseActivity().getToolbar();
    final FrameLayout cv = getBaseActivity().getContentView();

    int translation = show ? 0 : -tt.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(tt), translation).setDuration(200);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float translationY = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(tt, translationY);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams clp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) cv.getLayoutParams();
            clp.topMargin = tt.getHeight() + (int) translationY;
            cv.setLayoutParams(clp);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

This works fine, except for a flickering in the animation. I assume that using `setLayoutParams` is a costly method. `requestLayout()` is equally slow. How can I make this animation smoother? Can I reduce the frame rate somehow?

Note, that for certain reasons I cannot use `setTranslationY` and the built-in animations of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: did you find a way to avoid flickering?

Comment: unfortunately not.